# Tornado Auth (Twittermixin) issue

Tags: python, oauth, tornado

I am currently trying to use tornado to display my twitter streams. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import logging
from tornado.auth import TwitterMixin
from tornado.escape import json_decode, json_encode
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line, parse_config_file
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, authenticated, HTTPError

define('port', default=8080, help="port to listen on")
define('config_file', default='secrets.cfg',
       help='filename for additional configuration')

define('debug', default=True, group='application',
       help="run in debug mode (with automatic reloading)")
# The following settings should probably be defined in secrets.cfg
define('twitter_consumer_key', type=str, group='application')
define('twitter_consumer_secret', type=str, group='application')
define('cookie_secret', type=str, group='application',
       default='this is a string',
       help="signing key for secure cookies")

class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    COOKIE_NAME = "uuser"
    def get_current_user(self):
        user_json = self.get_secure_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME)
        if not user_json:
            print("  No user_json")
            return None
        print("  Yes user_json")
        return json_decode(user_json)

class MainHandler(BaseHandler, TwitterMixin):
    @authenticated
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        timeline = yield self.twitter_request(
            '/statuses/home_timeline',
            access_token = self.current_user['access_token'])
        self.render('home.html', timeline=timeline)

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler, TwitterMixin):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument('oauth_token', None):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user()
            print('  user:', type(user))
            del user["description"]
            self.set_secure_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME, json_encode(user))
            print('  get_secure_cookie:', self.get_secure_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME) )
            self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/'))
        else:
            print("  Authorize_redirecting...")
            yield self.authorize_redirect(callback_uri=self.request.full_url())

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("user")

def main():
    parse_command_line(final=False)
    parse_config_file(options.config_file)

    app = Application(
        [
            (r'/', MainHandler),
            (r'/login', LoginHandler),
            (r'/logout', LogoutHandler),
        ],
        login_url='/login',
        **options.group_dict('application'))
    app.listen(options.port)

    logging.info('Listening on http://localhost:%d' % options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So my understanding of the flow is as follows:

1.) Visit '/' - MainHandler, the `@authenticated` will redirect to `login_url` if the user is not logged in.

2.) Visit '/login' - LoginHandler, `self.authorize_redirect(callback_uri=self.request.full_url())` will append oauth_token argument at the end of url, and re-visit '/login'

3.)  Visit'/login' - LoginHandler, obtain user from `self.get_authenticated_user()`, and `set_secure_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME, json_encode(user))`

And here is the problem I think, I can't seem to set the cookie. When I try to access it immediately by `self.get_secure_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME)`, it returns `None`, and hence it keeps on re-visiting '/login'

Can anybody offer some help to my problem? Maybe it is something very obvious I am not seeing. Thanks

I have also set `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` as the callback url on my twitter app setting, not sure if this has any contribution to the problem.

Comment: Okay I am sure `set_secure_cookie(name=self.COOKIE_NAME, value=json_encode(user))` is the cause of the issue, it never manage to set cookie on my browser. I have checked the `user` object exists and is a `dict`, and `json_encode` does return a string value...so there must be something with `set_secure_cookie` function....

Answer (score -2):

Final solution!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import uuid
import logging
from tornado.auth import TwitterMixin
from tornado.escape import json_decode, json_encode, url_escape, url_unescape
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line, parse_config_file
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, authenticated, HTTPError
from urllib.parse import quote
import re

define('port', default=8080, help="port to listen on")
define('config_file', default='secrets.cfg',
       help='filename for additional configuration')

define('debug', default=True, group='application',
       help="run in debug mode (with automatic reloading)")
# The following settings should probably be defined in secrets.cfg
define('twitter_consumer_key', type=str, group='application')
define('twitter_consumer_secret', type=str, group='application')
# define('cookie_secret', type=str, group='application',
#        default='thisisastring',
#        help="signing key for secure cookies")


class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    COOKIE_NAME = "user"
    def get_current_user(self):
        user_json = self.get_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME)
        if not user_json:
            print("\n  - Cannot obtain cookie from client browser")
            return None
        print("\n  - Cookie obtained from client browser")
        return json_decode(user_json)

class MainHandler(BaseHandler, TwitterMixin):
    @authenticated
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        print("\n  - Obtaining timeline from twitter")
        timeline = yield self.twitter_request(
            '/statuses/home_timeline',
            access_token = self.current_user)
        self.render('home.html', timeline=timeline)

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler, TwitterMixin):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument('oauth_token', None):
            print("\n  - Authenticating with oauth_token...")
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user()
            encoded_token = json_encode(user['access_token'])

            # remove certain ascii symbols which are rejected  
            # by self.set_cookie() function...
            encoded_token = re.sub(r"[\x00-\x20]", '', encoded_token)

            # save encoded token as cookie  
            self.set_cookie(name=self.COOKIE_NAME, value=encoded_token)
            self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/'))
        else:
            print("\n  - Authorize_redirecting...")
            yield self.authorize_redirect(callback_uri=self.request.full_url())

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie(self.COOKIE_NAME)

def main():
    parse_command_line(final=False)
    parse_config_file(options.config_file)

    app = Application(
        [
            (r'/', MainHandler),
            (r'/login', LoginHandler),
            (r'/logout', LogoutHandler),
        ],
        login_url='/login',
        cookie_secret=str(uuid.uuid4().bytes),
        **options.group_dict('application'))
    app.listen(options.port)

    logging.info('Listening on http://localhost:%d' % options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```